# Qt 5.6, how to draw text with a different fill and outline colours

Tags: qt, fill, outline, drawtext

I'm using Qt5.6, I am drawing text on a video window, however sometimes the text is not very readable due to the video content in the window.  I'm current drawing the text on the painter context with the 'drawText' method.  Whilst I can set the pen colour which controls the fill, I do not seem to be able to set an outline colour.

I would like to draw the text with a black outline to make it stand out.  Unfortunately firewall where I am working makes life very difficult and any useful web-site that might help, seems to be blocked, hence this post.

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `QPainterPath::addText()`.

You can add the text to a path, then `QPainter::fillPath()` and `QPainter::strokePath()` the path.

Or you can direcly use `QPainter::drawPath()` with a brush and pen set.

Comment: Is there an alternative for QOainter::drawText with QRect as a parameter?
QPainter::drawPath() doesn't accept rect.